# Regex Replace doesn't obey $1

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var input = document.getElementById('textinput').value;
var lines = input.split('\n');
var output = '';       
$.each(lines, function(key, line) {

    for(var iii=0; iii<=key; iii++) //for each line
    {
        var filenameRegex = /^\* \[\[Media:(.+?)(\|)/;
        var results = lines[iii].match(filenameRegex);
        var filename;
        console.log('lines[iii]= '+lines[iii]);
            if(results!==null && results.length!== 0)
            {
                  output += lines[iii].replace(filenameRegex,'$1'); 
            }
    }
```

I try hard but the output is always  `output += lines[iii].replace(filenameRegex,'$1$2')` 
even though I only want $1

Example input: * [[Media:importantstuff|unimportantstuff]]

Expected output: importantstuff

Actual output: importantstuffunimportantstuff]]

Comment: Also, there is no need to do `for` loop, since you already have `$.each(lines...`.

Comment: Not the problem, but just in case: using /^\* \[\[Media:(.+?)(\|)/ in replace will only replace the first occurence, add a "g" letter at the end of the regex ot make it global.

Comment: full code here http://codepen.io/raindrop11/pen/riBIw tell me if you can't access it

Comment: Why don't you just remove the 2nd pair of parenthesis if you don't want any $2 captured ?

Comment: The input is `* [[Media:importantstuff|unwantedstuff]]` on each line

Comment: +Raindrop please add an example of input, expected output and actual output into you question text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you are looking for this:

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/geuID)

Code:

```
var filenameRegex = /^\* \[\[Media:(.+?)\|.*/;
var results = lines[iii].match(filenameRegex);
var filename;
console.log('lines[' + iii + ']= ' + lines[iii]);
console.log('key[' + iii + ']= ' + key);
if (results !== null && results.length !== 0) {
    output += lines[iii].replace(filenameRegex, '$1');
}
```